# How to save command as well as output of that command to a file

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, console, tee

Hi I want to save both output of a command and the command that has been run to create the output into the same single file. I understand either of

```
*some_command* > file.txt   
*some_command* | tee file.txt
```

can be done but either case the *some_command*  doesn't get saved into the file but only the output of it gets saved. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: You want the command printed for logging reasons?

Comment: You are probably looking for `script` which will create a new session and store everything on the terminal in a file called "typescript" until you leave the session.

Comment: @pLumo yes I am trying to log.

Comment: Do you want the command as entered on the command line (e.g. `ls -l "$dir"/*.txt`) or the resulting command that was run, after all expansions (e.g. `ls -l ./foo/file1.txt ./foo/file2.txt`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the command in an array, print and run it:

```
# Define command
mycmd=(some_command -o "some option")

# Print command
echo "${mycmd[@]}"

# Run command
"${mycmd[@]}"
```

[See also.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Note, this will strip the quotes when printing the command.

---

Put it in a function:

```
lognrun(){ echo "$@"; "$@"; }
lognrun some_command -o "some_option" > logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subshell with `set -x`:

```
$ ( set -x; printf '%s\n' a b "c d"; ) 2>&1 | tee logfile
+ printf '%s\n' a b 'c d'
a
b
c d
```

Comment: Note that the trace output generated by `set -x` is not actually showing the commands as they were given to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the 'script'-command?

```
$ script logfile
$ somecommand
lots of command output...
```

This will log everything you do on the shell to logfile.  Stop with Ctrl+D.

If you only need it for one command, you can use the '-c'-option:

```
-c, --command command
    Run the command rather than an interactive shell.
    This makes it easy for a script to capture the output of a program
    that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.
```

Comment: script seems fine but it also saves all other information like time of script etc. I don't think I need them.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that...  Some postprocessing then:

script -c "ls -lvhF" temp/logfile ;
sed '1d' temp/logfile | head -n -2

to get rid of the unneeded extras.